# At what percent can I land a perfect combo with Captain Falcon?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

It is commonly accepted that the easiest way to set up for a f-air combo with Captain Falcon is to use a running down throw into the forward air. More often than not, this actually ends up failing. At what percent is the knockback from the down throw perfect to set up for a forward air, especially hitting with the sweetspot?

Comment: It is usually easier to string up air into forward air

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this question can get a concrete response due the fact that all the characters got [diferent weight](http://kuroganehammer.com/Smash4/Weight) so they perceive different [knock-back](http://www.ssbwiki.com/knockback#Formula) at the same percentage.

I would gess it's close to 30%, before the grab.

Comment: Assuming the character was one of average weight, do you think the 30% would work?

Comment: That is fairly accurate! Thanks for your response!

Comment: @TrentonJames If you found the answer useful, please feel free to mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the small tick icon under the vote arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The higher the weight the higher the percentage necessary. On average, depending on your timing, 30% is a good starting point. Higher weight characters take around 40 to 50 percent, accounting for the heavier characters, fast falling, etc. Lighter characters only take 25 to 35 percent, again depending on other factors.
I experimented and this is accurate and makes the falcon knee hit at least 75% of the time depending on player skill.